# Move SQL Server database with Change Tracking enabled

Tags: sql-server, azure, sql-server-2012, virtual-machine

I have a number of database on premises that use change tracking to enable 2-way synchronisation with remote disconnected clients; the idea being when the clients connect online they sync their changes and pull down all others.

I need to move the database to an instance on a virtualised server in Azure (note: not Azure SQLDB) but every option - backup/restore, bacpac, etc - seems to reset that version number that SQL Server uses for Change Tracking.

Does anyone know of a way of moving a SQL Server 2012 database to another instance and retaining the Version Number and existing change tracking info?

Thanks

Comment: Not an answer, but it is a good idea in any case to make your solutions robust against the incidental loss of change tracking information, as [this article](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/cc280447) explains. If you don't yet have any way to "start over", now might be a good time to work on a solution for that.

Comment: ^ I second this. If your applications gets out-of-sync by more than the change history it will need to do this anyway! So you really have to implement this, especially with a cloud solution!